# Unable to test redux-observable epic

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, rxjs6

I intend to write unit test for the following epic

```
// Actions
const actionCreator = actionCreatorFactory('PARENT_DIRECTORY');
export const fetchPage = actionCreator.async<Page, ParentPage>('FETCH_PAGE');

export const fetchParentDirectoryEpic: Epic = action$ =>
  action$.pipe(
    filter(fetchPage.started.match),
    mergeMap((action) => {
      return getDirectoryPage(action.payload).pipe(
        map(response => fetchPage.done({ params: action.payload, result: response.response })),
        catchError(error => of(fetchPage.failed({ params: action.payload, error: error })))
      );
    })
  );
```

I mocked the getDirectoryPage like below -

```
import { AjaxResponse, AjaxError } from 'rxjs/ajax';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

export function getDirectoryPage(page: any): Observable<AjaxResponse> {
  switch (page.index) {
    case 0:
      return Observable.create({'data': [], page: 0, pages: 1});
    default:
      return Observable.create(observer => {
        return new AjaxError('Something bad happened!', null, null);
      });
  }
}
```

and following is how my unit test looks like -

```
describe('fetchParentDirectoryEpic Epic', () => {
    it('dispatches the correct actions when it is successful', async (done) => {
        const expectedOutputAction = outputAction;

        fetchParentDirectoryEpic(inputAction, initialState, null)
            .subscribe(actualOutputAction => {
                expect(actualOutputAction).toBe(expectedOutputAction)
                done()
            }
        );
    });
});
```

Issue is that the call to `fetchParentDirectoryEpic(inputAction, initialState, null)` results in an Observable which doesn't have subscribe method. As I understand, the method is available with `ActionObservable` but I am unable to create its instance using a payload.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was related to how I was creating expectedOutputAction. Its supposed to be an `Action` and not an `ActionObservable`.

After setting expectedOutputAction in the following manner, test worked out fine -

```
expectedOutputAction = {
  type: fetchPage.done.type, 
  result: {'data': [], page: 0, pages: 1}, 
  params: inputAction.payload
}
```